# How to PHP Search when miss one character?

Tags: php, mysql, search, full-text-search, sphinx

I'm finding a solution for search. There are few product with name:

1. USB Kingston 8GB
2. USB Kingmax 8GB
3. USB Transcend 8GB
4. USB Sandisk 4GB

I'm using **mysql** database, I've tried **FullText Search**.

`SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE MATCH('productName') AGAINST ('usb 8g')`.

and also **sphinx** but i did't get any results when type "**usb 8g**". But "usb 8gb", it's worked.

And I also need when user type '**ubs** 8gb', it's will return correct results too.

Any solution to auto-recognize like Google ?

Comment: "8g" is ignored because it's below the 4 character minimum for full text searching.  As this is a feature of the product it may be better implementing a different way of searching for it, such as listing the various available sizes (2, 4, 8, 16, etc) and letting the user select the ones they're interested in with checkboxes or similar.

Comment: I've changed ft_min_word_len to 2 but it's didn't worked. But thank you anyway for the listing idea.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use wildcard character `%` to match part of data string.

Have not tested, but should work like:

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE MATCH('productName') AGAINST ('usb 8g%')
```

P.S. Please sanitize user input before sending to SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks, But when user type '8g usb' maybe it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

On Sphinx for this specific situation, using say `min_prefix_len=2` and `expand_keywords=1` would work. This makes part word matches possible. Ie so that '8g' will match '8gb', in effect the query becomes '8g*'. There is also a wildcard on the end of 'usb' as in its also matching 'usb*' - that shouldnt really affect anything,as unlikely yo have many other words beginning with those chars.

Ultimately its a tradeoff, on how 'fuzzy' to make the search, as this could introduce all sorts of side effects. Difficult to think of a good example, but something like searching for 'case' would then match 'casebook'. But case and casebook at compeltely different things.